# Java script as a arguments of ruby function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I use java script as a  arguments of ruby function?

For example i want

`<%= label :placehoder => result of javascript %>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because the ruby part will run on the server before the javascript gets a chance to run in the browser. You can use a server side language to build javascript dynamically, but not the other way around.

A workaround would be to run an ajax request from javascript to pass data to the server.

Comment: So I will not be able to pass the value from one form to another?